# Javascript command "return" doubling itself inadvertently

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, return

I have the following problem:

I was trying, inside a common HTML page mixed with some Javascript, to write a simple program so that a specific div would be filled with the result of a function.

The  result of the function consists of a string of text, below a row of dashes with as many dashes as the number of characters inside the text string.

My code is as follows, inside the body:

```
<div id="div1"></div>

<script>
let tab = "";

function result(text) {
for (i in text) {
tab += '-';
}
return "<p>" + tab + "<br>" + text + "</p>";
}

document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = result("Bear") + result("Bear") + result("Bear");
</script>
```

The rendered HTML returns the following result:
[image]

Only the first invocation of the function works as expected: 4 dashes for 4 letters. But the second invocation renders twice as many dashes, and the third one three times as many.

Perhaps "return" is not the command to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *only* set `tab` to an empty string at the start of the program.

You **don't** set it to an empty string inside the function.

So it never gets *reset* to an empty string.

Every time you call the function, `tab` just gets dashes added to whatever is there.

If you want to reset it every time the function is called, then reset it **inside** the function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and straightforward answer!
So I just needed to declare the "tab" string inside the function... I just did it, and it worked as I had planned. Many thanks once again from a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It waa already answered. Still a different view could help:

#### Issue &. Fix

**Each** call of `result(text)` is adding dashes to the **global** variable `tab` (here 3 times the same length: 4 + 4 + 4).
Usually `let` keyword is described with following:

- declare a *scoped* variable, which is only valid and has a lifetime within the current [scope] (here: for the **whole script**, not only inside the function).

Commented and properly formatted (proper indentation eases readability!) your script:

```js
let tab = ""; // declared at start of the script, means global scope

function result(text) {
    // move declaration here so it always is reborn (local scope = new lifetime)
    for (i in text) {
        tab += '-';
    }
    return "<p>" + tab + "<br>" + text + "</p>";
}
```

From your described intend  *scoped* should rather be **declared inside the function**. So it has **local scope** (known inside the function only).
Moreover it will automatically be reset at each call of the function.

#### Alternative

In old console usage (Text-UI) and still in ASCII-Art the basic method to draw a textual line with any character like dashes `-` was described either of:

- fill width of *n* characters with character *a*
- return string which contains character *a* repeated for *n* times

So they invented functions like `fillString( a, n )` or `a.repeat( n )`.
Similar can be done in JavaScript.

Benefits:

1. you can **parameterize the filler character**, e.g to `=` or `_`
2. you can **easily reuse** this generic function

#### Bonus: Review

My experience taught me to pay attention to **naming** in code.
**Express intend and purpose**, so you and everybody else can see now – and in 6 months – the mraning of variables and functions at a glance.

- most functions return a result, this does more: `function addSameWidthLineAbove(text)`
- `let line` or `textualBorder` or `dashes`